plz any help me to make the this border design
Image
enter image description here
plz make it
In this image a border design that have different coner design like squer plz make it any one  .
help me any to create this in html use any thing like boostrap
To create this border with different square designs in the corners, you can use the following approach with HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap for styling enhancements.

"To create a certificate border with different square designs in the corners, you can use the following approach with HTML, CSS, and optionally Bootstrap for styling enhancements. Here's the modified design:" - what are you talking about here. Sounds like you are quoting half of what was suggested to you elsewhere ...?

Go look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-image

Hi, welcome, but please be aware that SO isn't an ab initio coding service. You need to make some attempt at coding this yourself (look into CSS borders as already suggested) and if you are still stuck then modify your question by including your code with a description of what isn't working.

CSS Outer Border
..outer-border:before, .outer-border:after, .inner-border:before, .inner-border:after {   content: "";   width: 20px;   height: 20px;   display: block;   position: absolute; } .outer-border:before {   border-top: 2px #ffffff solid;   border-left: 2px #ffffff solid;   border-right: 2px orange solid;   border-bottom: 2px orange solid;   top: -2px;   left: -2px; } .outer-border:after {   border-top: 2px #ffffff solid;   border-bottom: 2px orange solid;   border-right: 2px #ffffff solid;   border-left: 2px orange solid;   top: -2px;   right: -2px; }

CSS Inner Border
`.inner-border:before {
border-bottom: 2px #ffffff solid;
border-left: 2px #ffffff solid;
border-right: 2px orange solid;
border-top: 2px orange solid;
bottom: -9px;
left: -9px;
}
.inner-border:after {
border-right: 2px #ffffff solid;
border-top: 2px orange solid;
border-bottom: 2px #ffffff solid;
border-left: 2px orange solid;
bottom: -9px;
right: -9px;
}`

HTML Code
`

 
 
`
Since answering on this post is blocked, I have provided the solution in the comments. CSS Code -
`.outer-border {
width: 600px;
height: 400px;
position: relative;
border: 2px orange solid;
margin: 0 auto;
}
.inner-border {
width: 586px;
height: 386px;
position: relative;
border: 2px orange solid;
margin: 5px;
}`

@raj I apppreciate that you are trying to help. But where did you get those fixed dimensions from - the OP has not told us anything about sizing (and it's quite likely they need something responsive). Also, I can't see where you have colored in between the lines as shown in the picture. And we need the OP to show us their basic HTML structure, or to tell us that it can be changed, before adding elements to the DOM just to get a visual effect.

@AHaworth I think my solution is good enough for the OP to get started, it solves the problem that OP is facing, the dimensions/responsiveness that is something OP hasn't specified. Not sure what you are referring to "where you have colored in between the lines", the entire html/css code is there in the comments to get the result the OP has asked for.

@raj the picture given has a yellow coloring between the orange lines.

@AHaworth Sorry I don't see any yellow coloring.
